# Cobb-Douglas utility function. Deriving the price index with N discrete goods functions

Tags: cobb-douglas

how do you get the final form of the price index for a cobb-douglas with n discrete goods? I can't get to the solution where e(p,1) = logP = the sum of (shares * log(P))

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be easier to use the log form for the Cobb-Douglas: $\ln(u) = \sum_i \alpha_i \ln(q_i)$. We can also assume that $\sum_j \alpha_j = 1$.
The expenditure function is given by:
$$
\min_{q} \sum_i p_i q_i \text{ s.t. } \sum_i \alpha_i \ln(q_i) = \ln(u).
$$
The first order conditions give:
$$
\begin{align*}
&p_i = \lambda \frac{\alpha_i}{q_i}.\\
&\ln(u) = \sum_j \alpha_j \ln(q_j).
\end{align*}
$$
Substituting the first into the second is given by:
$$
\ln(u) = \sum_j \alpha_j \ln(\lambda) + \sum_j \alpha_j \ln(\alpha_j/p_j).
$$
Then (as $\sum_j \alpha_j = 1$):
$$
\ln(\lambda) = \ln(u) - \sum_j \alpha_j \ln(\alpha_j/p_j).
$$

So:
$$
q_i = \frac{\alpha_i}{p_i} u \prod_j \left(p_j/\alpha_j\right)^{\alpha_j}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $p_i$ and adding over all $i$ (taking into account $\sum_j \alpha_j = 1$) gives:
$$
\sum_j p_j q_j = u \prod_j (p_j/\alpha_j)^{\alpha_j}
$$
Let $s_i = \frac{p_i q_i}{\sum_j p_j q_j}$ be the expenditure share for good $i$. From the above two equations, we get:
$$
s_i = \alpha_i.
$$
This gives the conventional knowledge that Cobb-Douglas utility functions lead to constant expenditure shares (equal to $\alpha_i$).

Now,
$$
c(p,u) = \sum_{j} p_j q_j = u \prod_j (p_j/\alpha_j)^{\alpha_j}
$$
So:
$$
\ln(c(p,u)) = \ln(u) + \sum_j \alpha_j\left[\ln(p_j) - \ln(\alpha_j)\right].
$$

Now, take two price levels $p^0$ and $p^1$. Then the log price index is given by:
$$
\ln\left(\frac{c(p^1,u)}{c(p^0,u)}\right) = \ln(c(p^1,u)) - \ln(c(p^0,u)) = \sum_j \alpha_j \left[\ln(p^1_j) - \ln(p^0_j)\right] = \sum_j s_j \ln\left(\frac{p^1_j}{p^0_j}\right).
$$
Equivalently:
$$
\frac{c(p^1,u)}{c(p^0,u)} = \prod_i \left(\frac{p^1_j}{p^0_j}\right)^{s_j}.
$$